# Copy a configmap but with another name in the same namespace (kubernetes/kubectl)

Tags: kubernetes

I have a configmap `my-config` in a namespace and need to make a copy (part of some temporary experimentation) but with another name so I end up with :

```
my-config
my-config-copy
```

I can do this with:

```
kubectl get cm my-config -o yaml > my-config-copy.yaml
```

edit the name manually followed by:

```
kubectl create -f my-config-copy.yaml
```

But is there a way to do it automatically in one line?

I can get some of the way with:

```
kubectl get cm my-config --export -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

but I am missing the part with the new name (since names are immutable I know this is not standard behavior).

Also preferably without using export since:

*Flag --export has been deprecated, This flag is deprecated and will be removed in future.*

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello @u123. Have you cinsidered using the [kubectl cp](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp) command?

Comment: Thats for copying content into containers. My post is about k8s resources/manifests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this by combining kubectl's `patch` and `apply` functions.

```
 kubectl patch cm source-cm -p '{"metadata":{ "name":"target-cm"}}' --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

`source-cm` and `target-cm` are the config map names

Comment: That gives: Error: invalid argument "client" for "--dry-run" flag: strconv.ParseBool: parsing "client": invalid syntax I then tried with --dry-run=true which creates the copied object

Comment: probably you are on an old version

"the boolean and unset values for the --dry-run flag are deprecated and a value --dry-run=server|client|none will be required in a future version."

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.18.md#kubectl-1